# Incrementing a mysql field when i add data to another field

Tags: mysql

Im new at mysql. I'm creating a comment system as a mysql exercise, where users can comment on different articles, and also reply to comments of other users on that article, like a tree.

I have created two mysql tables (articles and comments). The articles store different articles, and comments store all the comments related to an article.

```
The article table:
    article_id        - unique auto increment integer (primary key)
    text              - text of the article
    number_of_replies - total number of people who commented on this article

The comment table:
    comment_id        - unique auto increment integer (primary key)
    article_id        - article being replied to
    parent_id         - the comment_id this comment is replying to, zero if root
    number_of_replies - number of people who replied to this comment
    comment           - the text of the comment
```

Articles have unique id called article_id

When someone comments on an article, the comment gets inserted into the comment table, and comment_id gets updated, and the article_id gets stored as well.

If someone replies to the article itself, then the parent_id is set to 0 on the comment table entry, and also add 1 to the number_of_replies in the article table for that article_id.

When someone replies to comment_id 1, a new comment_id 2 is inserted into the table that has its parent_id set to 1, while at the same time adding 1 to the number_of_replies column of comment_id 1, and also add 1 to the number_of_replies on the article table for that article_id.

So when i add a comment i have to do three mysql operations

1. Add the new comment to the comment table (updating all the fields)
2. Add 1 to the number_of_replies for that article in the articles table
3. If replying to an existing comment, Add 1 to the comment corresponding to the parent_id in the comments table

Is it possible to do all three operations at the same time? If so, what are the mysql statements to do so. If not, what are the statements to do them individually?

Im new to mysql, so if there is something not clear, or i ask stupid question, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: you could combine them all into a single stored procedure so they can be easily executed in one command, and wrap the statements in a transaction so that if one fails, they all do (so you don't get inconsistent data). Or you could look at triggers as another option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the number of comments/replies in the table, you should simply query the database when you need those numbers, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_table WHERE article_id = ?

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_table WHERE parent_id = ?
```

The only reason to store them like you are would be as an optimization, but I think that that would be an incremental speed improvement at best, even on a large website.

Otherwise, you should do like ADyson said and use procedures and transactions.